# Setting up project.json file correctly in VS Code Mono

Tags: asp.net, .net, mono, visual-studio-code, dnx

Im a long time .NET developer but new to using VS Code on my Mac. I am trying to setup references in the project.json file but keep recieving missing ref errors. I am trying different things, but I guess it would help to understand what are all of the tartget frameworks that I can add in my Frameworks Section? I looked on the web and noticied "net45","dnx451","dnx50", etc. but what do they all mean and is there a website that simple explains each Framework I can choose?

Secondly I am very confused at where to actually put the reference?? I have a .net 4.5.1 project that I am converting. I am just putting them in different places and not truly understanding what I am doing. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt, but I am not learning. For example one of my Classes has uses the Math.Round function and I cant compile because it says the name 'Math' does not exist in the current context.

To summarize. Can anyone tell me or share a link about the different frameworks I can choose in my project.json file Framework section? And where do I properly put the reference. For example "System" because system.math is not working.

My project.json file

```
    {
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "packExclude": [
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc",
        "**.config",
        "**.csproj"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Owin": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Cors": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Security": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core": "2.2.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin": "2.2.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Razor": "3.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization": "1.1.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost": "5.2.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages": "3.2.3",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
        "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net45": { 
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.IO": "4.0.0-*"
            }
        },

        "dnx451": {
            "compilationOptions": {//I dont even know what this means
                "define": [
                    "ASYNC"//This either. Why?? I just seen it online
                ],
                "warningsAsErrors": true
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Net.Http":"4.0.0-*",


                "Tools": "0.0-*",
                "BL": "0.0-*"
            },
            "frameworkAssemblies": {

                "System.Drawing": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.Web": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.Net": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.Xml": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.Core": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.Xml.Linq": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.Configuration": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.0-*",
                "System.Net.Http.WebRequest":"4.0.0-*"                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors I am receiving
Application startup exception: Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.RoslynCompilationException: /Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ImageHelper.cs(8,3): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Flags' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Global.asax.cs(50,32): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Global.asax.cs(50,32): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0122: 'AsyncMessageProcessor.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ApiRequestLoggingHandler.cs(49,33): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ApiRequestLoggingHandler.cs(49,33): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpRequestBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ApiRequestLoggingHandler.cs(49,50): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpRequest' to 'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinRequest'
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(89,67): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(87,46): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(37,10): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(42,10): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(47,10): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(52,10): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(57,10): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(72,10): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(77,10): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(144,9): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(146,26): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/AppContext.cs(146,26): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0122: 'ServiceContext.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ImageHelper.cs(94,15): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InvalidOperationException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ImageHelper.cs(160,8): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0103: The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ImageHelper.cs(161,8): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0103: The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ImageHelper.cs(167,21): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0103: The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/ImageHelper.cs(169,22): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0103: The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/UploadedImageProvider.cs(83,11): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/UploadedImageProvider.cs(83,11): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS1674: 'ServiceContext': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/UploadedImageProvider.cs(85,26): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Disposable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/OAuth/ApiOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.cs(68,43): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Users/MY/Desktop/Ci/core/ApiSite/Classes/OAuth/ApiOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.cs(68,43): DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpRequestBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Having similar problems with local dependencies. But i can answer a few of your questions. `compilationOptions` are exactly that. compilation-options. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fdbz5xd.aspx basically command-line options to be passed to the compiler. I can attempt to answer most of your questions in an answer, but it will not be complete.